# Get non finite domains bounds with C# SWI-Prolog DLL

Tags: c#, swi-prolog, clpfd

I am using Swi-Prolog Csharp DLL and CLP(FD).
I have the following Prolog file :

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

constr(V0,V1,V2,C0,C1,C2) :-
   ((V0 #= 1901) #\/ (V0 #= 1750)) #<==> C0,
   ((V1 #= 3) #\/ (5 #= V1)) #<==> C1,
   ((V2 #>= 1)) #<==> C2.

config(V1,V2) :- constr(1750,V1,V2,1,1,1).
```

V0,V1,V2 are my variables. C0,C1,C2 are my constraints reification variables.
When calling `config(V1,V2).` , I want to get the V1 and V2 domain values such that all constraints are satisfied.

When using in SWI-Prolog interface, I get :

```
1 ?- config(V1,V2).
V1 in 3\/5,
V2 in 1..sup.
```

Now I am wondering how to get this result in the C# port of SWI-Prolog.
Calling `query.SolutionVariables[0]["V1"]` or `query.SolutionVariables[0]["V2"]` give me intermediate variables.

For V1 I could use a labelling strategy (`res(X,L) :- setof(X, indomain(X), L).`), but that will not work for V2 as it corresponds to a non-finite domain.

So, in a nutshell, how can I get the non-finite domain info for a solution variable with C# Swipl DLL ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the C++ ffi. Rather, use `copy_term/3`

Comment: Could you please show me how to use it ?

Answer (score 2):

```
?- Goal_0 = config(V1,V2), Goal_0, copy_term(Goal_0, Goal_0, C_0s).
Goal_0 = config(V1, V2),
C_0s = [clpfd:(V1 in 3\/5), clpfd:(V2 in 1..sup)],
V1 in 3\/5,
V2 in 1..sup.
```

Thus, use `copy_term/3` to get all the constraints attached.  Then use the common term [ffi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffi).

Comment: Do you mean I have to use copy_term/2 after what you wrote ? and what is the common term "ffi" ?

Comment: It's `copy_term/3` not `/2`.  (See link above for ffi)

Comment: Ok so now with my C# functions I get C_0s = [clpfd:(_G1402 in 3\/5), clpfd:(_G1848 in 1..sup)]  ...also with V1 = _G1402 and V2 = _G1848. How to have reified results ?

Comment: What do you mean by reified results?

Comment: That may not be the right word, I want to have `[clpfd:(V1 in 3\/5), clpfd:(V2 in 1..sup)]`, not `[clpfd:(_G1402 in 3\/5), clpfd:(_G1848 in 1..sup)]`

Comment: I was also thinking of forcing the bounding my variables, then getting min and max of possible values to redetermine it is a non finite domain : `V1 in -999999..999999, V2 in -999999..999999, config(V1,V2),res(V1,V1out), res(V2,V2out),min_list(V1out,V1min),max_list(V1out,V1max),min_list(V2out,V2min),max_list(V2out,V2max).
V1out = [3, 5],
V2out = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12|...],
V1min = 3,
V1max = 5,
V2min = 4,
V2max = 999999,
V1 in 3\/5,
V2 in 4..999999.` Quite ugly, but...

Comment: You have some fundamental difficulties understanding variables as such.  I'd suggest that you leave that C++ part, and just concentrate on learning Prolog first.

Comment: I agree with you on the fact I am a beginner in Prolog. That's why I am here. I know how to get all possible values for variables that belong to finite domains, with the use of `res(X,L) :- setof(X, indomain(X), L).` My problem is when X is not sufficiently instantiated, i.e. belongs to a non-finite domain (e.g. [1;sup[ ) I don't know how to efficiently detect and show these cases.